# Why is list Empty?

Tags: c#, observablecollection, iasyncresult, asynccallback

I am able to access the list (**ListData**) value from within its class, but if I try to reference the list from outside of the class, it shows it as an empty list.

I add objects  to ListData in the getVideoList method.

I added this piece of code and it works now (Polling method) , **Is this ineffiencient ?**

```
 IAsyncResult result = request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(getVideoList), state);
            while (result.IsCompleted == false)
            {
               Thread.Sleep(1000);
             }
```

---

```
Public class otherclass{
    static void main(string [] args){
      RestProcess process = new RestProcess(videoListURI);
      process.initilaizeRest();

      foreach (VideoSeriesElement ele in process.ListData)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(ele.id);
        Console.WriteLine(ele.title);
        Console.WriteLine(ele.href);
        Console.WriteLine(ele.image);
      }

      Console.ReadLine();
  }

}
```

---

```
public class RestProcess
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    readonly string blankimage = "http://images1.test.com/properties/NoThumbnail_HD.jpg";
    public RestProcess(string uri)
    {
        URI = uri;
        ListData = new ObservableCollection<VideoSeriesElement>();
    } 
    public ObservableCollection<VideoSeriesElement> ListData{get;set;}


    public void initilaizeRest()
    {
        WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(URI);
        request.Method = "GET";

        // RequestState is a custom class to pass info to the callback
        RequestState state = new RequestState(request, URI);
        IAsyncResult result = request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(getVideoList), state);
    }

    public string URI{get;set;}

    /// <summary>
    /// getVideoList
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="result"></param>
    public void getVideoList(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        RequestState state = (RequestState)result.AsyncState;
        WebRequest request = (WebRequest)state.Request;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);

        try
        {
            TextReader textreader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()); 
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(textreader);


            foreach(XElement videoSeriesEle in doc.Descendants("video-series"))
            {
                var videseriesEle = new VideoSeriesElement();    
                videseriesEle.id = videoSeriesEle.Attribute("id").Value;
                videseriesEle.href = videoSeriesEle.Attribute("href").Value;
                videseriesEle.title = videoSeriesEle.Element("title").Value;

                if (!videoSeriesEle.Element("images").IsEmpty && videoSeriesEle.Element("images").Elements("image") != null)
                {
                    var imagelist = videoSeriesEle.Element("images").Elements("image").ToList();
                    foreach (var ele in imagelist)
                    {
                        if (ele.Attribute("styleid").Value.Equals("5"))
                        {
                            if (videoSeriesEle.Element("images").Element("image").Attribute("href").Value != null)
                            {
                                videseriesEle.image = videoSeriesEle.Element("images").Element("image").Attribute("href").Value;
                            }

                        }
                    }

                }
                else { videseriesEle.image = blankimage; }


                //add object to list 
                ListData.Add(videseriesEle);

            }

            //Close streams 
            textreader.Close();
            response.Close();
        }
        catch (XmlException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="state"></param>
    /// <param name="timedOut"></param>
    private static void ScanTimeoutCallback(object state, bool timedOut)
    {
        if (timedOut)
        {
            RequestState reqState = (RequestState)state;
            if (reqState != null)
                reqState.Request.Abort();
            Console.WriteLine("aborted- timeout");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RestProcess.initilaizeRest()` method requests the data via an `IAsyncResult`, meaning the call to get the data is asynchronous. In your `otherClass` class, you attempt to process and loop through the `ListData` element immediately after calling `initilaizeRest()` and there is a very good chance that the data is not loaded yet.

To fix this, you should have a callback/event-handler in the `otherClass` that listens for when the data is populated.

Comment: Could direct me to Documentation on callback/event-handler ?

Answer (score 1):

You can expose IAsyncResult result as a property from the request.BeginGetResponse call in RestProcess and block in otherClass until the IAsyncResult.IsCompleted property is true, or use the WaitHandle exposed by it, but is there a reason that you're using the async BeginGetResponse call rather than the synchronous GetResponse call?

Comment: I don't believe GetResponse  is supported on Xbox360

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise you were developing for the 360. Check here for a couple of examples of how you can use something implementing the async pattern like BeginGetRespoonse: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=642 - polling and callbacks.